# Elasticsearch: private user documents

Tags: elasticsearch, data-access-layer, access-control

We're considering using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) for our webservice. Since ES operates at a low level, for authentication and authorization there has to be some layer above it. I see [Shields](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) which apparently can control on a roles-based level what a `user`, and `admin`, a `developer` etc. can do in the search index. What I could not find, however, is how to control data access on a user level: Every user has to have access to all public documents plus his/her private ones.

Is there an ES plugin/paradigm that handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea with Shield is to have a user group in the indexed document:

```
{
  "text":"Document 1 is public",
  "user_group": ["public"]
}
{
  "text":"Document 2 is restricted",
  "user_group": ["restricted"]
}
```

Then you can force a filter to be applied for a specified user group

```
# For users in group public
{"term" : {"user_group" : "public"}}

# For users in group restricted (can see public as well)
{"terms" : {"user_group" : ["public","restricted"]}}
```

Elasticsearch 2.0 / Shield 2.0 has improved [Document level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/setting-up-field-and-document-level-security.html#document-level-security). [Prior to that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/shield-1.3/limitations.html#limitations-filtered-aliases) you were forced to use Index Aliases.

[SearchGuard](http://floragunn.com/searchguard/audit-log) (a Shield alternative) behaves likes Shield: *dlsfilter* binds a user group with filter.

In both cases, binding a user to a document might be a difficult (impossible?) task, because everything is based on user groups/roles, not individual users. You could generate a group specific to each user though. Each time you add a user, it will force you to add a user group, and configure its specific grants.